How close is someone with 751cM
I am 75 years old.  A guy on Ancestry is in his mid/late 80s.  We live on opposite sides of the Atlantic (UK/Canada) but his grandparents came from the same town as my maternal grandmother and was a short distance from where her husband lived.
What could our relationship be?

This is exactly the kind of question that the Shared cM Project is designed to help with.
751 cM could be several relationships.  Take a look at the list there - some of those relationships you can eliminate immediately. (great-grandparent, for example).
Most likely, given your ages, is some kind of 1st cousin relationship (1st cousin, 1st cousin once removed, half first cousin).
